# How to calculate color of pixel with real-number coordinate

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, photo

[image: Original Image]

[image: Result Image]

The first picture is the original image and the second one is the image that is created by rearrange the pixel from the first one. As you can see, the edge of the curve looks like a staircase because the pixels are selected from the first picture by flooring the coordinates. Is there any possible way to smooth the edge like the anti-aliasing function in Photoshop.

Edit 4/26/2018:
From what Cris Luengo said, I implemented Bilinear Interpolation and apply it to the image. Here is the result(ignore the orange object).

[image: Bilinear Interpolation]

The curve near the orange object still looks like a stair case but the rest looks smoother. Are there any other algorithms that make it smoother? I find it confusing to implement Bicubic Interpolation but if it make the image smoother, I will try.

Comment: It's called interpolation. Instead of rounding coordinates, sample the image using interpolation.

Comment: there are 2 basic approaches: 1. one is compute the fraction of your target pixel into the 4 physical pixels and add each to its corresponding position via blending 2. the other is create the image as you did but in N times bigger resolution and than resize down to target resolution.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've tried implemeting Bilinear Interpolation and the result is in the post. Are there any other algorithms that make it smoother?

Comment: if you are not satisfied with interpolation result then you can use averaging/lowpass filter to blur/smooth image after interpolation

Comment: Ah, I see now. What happens near the orange object is that the output is scaled down significantly from the input. That makes it so that interpolation is not effective. It only works well when the scale stays similar or is increased, not when it is decreased. The solution is a bit more involved. @Spektre's 2nd solution would be a good approach in this case. The "resize down to target resolution" would then involve averaging the NxN input pixels that compose each output pixel. It is possible, but complex, to do this in one step. The intermediate step will make it a lot easier.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I think from Spektre's approach, N must be really large to fit the coordinates with high precision and will increase the time complexity significantly so I prefer Bicubic Interpolation(yeah, I finally did it) to this solution. It preserves contrast of the picture too. Thanks for both of your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've achieve my result using Bicubic Interpolation. Its time complexity isn't too high and it preserves the image contrast which is great for real image but not line art so I think this algorithm is adequate.

Possible solutions

1) Bilinear Interpolation

2) Bicubic Interpolation

3) Approach from N times larger image then resize it back